# An eigenvalue of certain family of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider the matrices
$$M_n=\left[\binom{i}j+\binom{2n+1-i}{j-i}+\binom{2n+1-i}j\right]_{i,j=0}^n.$$
I am convinced and hence would like to ask:

> **Question:** Is $0$ an eigenvalue of $M_n$?

Comment: Could you please provide some background for this matrix? I do not think 0 is an eigenvalue for each such matrix for each $n$.

Comment: Define a vector $v_n\in \mathbb{Z}^{n+1}$ by $$(v_n)_j=(-1)^j\left(\binom{n}{j}+\binom{n+1}{j}\right)$$ for all $j\in [0,n]$. Hence, except for alternating signs and the last entry, $v_n^T$ is equal to the last column of $M_n$. I conjecture that if $n$ is odd, then $v_n^TM_n=0$. This statement would imply that $0$ is an eigenvalue of $M_n$.

Comment: Correction: $v_n^T$ is related to the last row of $M_n$ (not the last column).

Comment: Multiplying on the left by the matrix $\left({i\choose j}\right)^{-1}$ appears to leave a diagonalizable matrix with eigenvalues $0,1,3$.

Comment: Now, we need a proof for what Philipp and MTyson are claiming.

Comment: For even $n$ I conjecture that the vector with $w_i=(-1)^i{{2(n+1)-i}\choose {n+1}}-2[i=n]$ is an eigenvector of $0$.